# How do I put out the fire of the second chest?

Tags: okami

In Taka Pass when you first enter it there is a cave you enter to make your way to Sakuya's Guardian Sapling. Beyond the spiral ramp where you would fight Waka there are 2 chest that are on fire.

One of the chest is by a pool of water which, using waterspout, allows you to douse the flames, further up there is a second chest on fire however I can't get the camera in a position where I have the water and the chest in view for me to use the Celestial Brush.

So how do I put out the flames of this second chest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to come back later, after you get a new ability.

> When you enter the windmill and get to the top, you'll get the Galestorm power and be able to cause winds. A wind will put out the fire.